# Pickle, efficiency - large data set

Tags: python, nltk, pickle

I've created several Naive Bayes classifiers and I've managed to save/load them using pickle and the code works correctly.

My classifiers will need to be run by someone else on a different machine, so I want to make sure it will work for someone else if I send them the code and the pickle files. The main part I'm concerned about is the saving and loading with pickle but if there's anything else that looks bad or inefficient I'm open to suggestions.

## Create Classifiers

```
import nltk
import pickle
import pandas

raw_data = {
'first_name': ['Zekey', 'Josh', 'Jake', 'Tina', 'Amy','Matt','Mitt','Anny','Anniy','Maxett'],
'last_name': ['Jacobson', 'Jacobson', 'Cooze', 'Cooze', 'Milner','Milner','Milner','Milner','Milner','Milner'],
'gender': ['X','X','Male','Female','Female','Male','Male','Female','Female','Female']}

df = pandas.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name','gender'])
last_name_dict = dict(iter(df.groupby("last_name")))

def gender_features(word):
    return {'first_letter': word[0], 'last_letter': word[-1]}

dct = {}
for last in df.last_name.unique():
    dct[last] = []
    for first,gender in zip(last_name_dict[last].first_name, last_name_dict[last].gender):
        dct[last].append((gender_features(first),gender))       

#TRAIN in a loop
traindct = {}
class_dct = {}

for last in df.last_name.unique():
    traindct['train_set_%s' % last] = dct[last][0:] 
    class_dct['Classif_%s'% last] = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(traindct['train_set_%s' % last])
```

## Save classifiers

```
f = open('classifya.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(class_dct, f)
f.close()
```

## Load classifiers

```
f = open('classifya.pickle', 'rb')
class_dct = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

## Classify

```
new_app=[]
for last in df.last_name.unique():
    for first,gender in zip(last_name_dict[last].first_name,last_name_dict[last].gender):
        new_app.append((first,last,gender,class_dct['Classif_%s'% last].classify(gender_features(first))))

df_output = pandas.DataFrame(new_app, columns=['First Name','Last Name','Gender','New Gender'])
```

Any advice on better/faster ways to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Globals is the set of module level variables and you are setting them propertly in your code ... if that's really what you want to do. It makes sense if you what the person writing the other module to use them by variable name (that is, when done, you now have a varable named `Classif_A`). I've done this kind of thing myself but its kinda a special case. Does the user want variables named like that (very specific code) or its own `class_dict` containing data, much like the original bundling code?

Comment: Use pickle protocol 2 - its faster and more compact. And your reader code doesn't work... your file is a bunch of pickled objects and your importer needs to decide which of those objects in input. To complicate things, you likely want some sort of delimiter like `\n` to separate those records.

Comment: This could get complicated.... your loader seems like it only wants to load a subset of the pickled items into memory. If so, you may want to pickle each item into its own file with a naming convention that makes it easy to find them later.

Comment: Is your comment saying it worked the latest update? Just want to make sure.

I don't know the proper lingo yet but I created the Classif_A, B, etc using nltk naive bayes classifier and they're not "normal" variables. For instance, when I put them in class_dct, the dictionary doesn't actually show up on my variables list where I can look at. But it still works to "call" all of the classifiers and use them.

I'd be fine loading them as a dictionary but I couldn't figure out how.

Also, the other person will understand Python less well than I know it now. They'll just be hitting a button.

Comment: It may help to move the reader into a separate program to see my confusion. How would these other programs generate the exact same list  `for last in df.last_name.unique():` so that the names match the stored objects? Is it possible to use simple mock objects to make a runnable example of what you are doing? Get rid of the df (or generate a small fake one) and the nltk and replace with dict or list or something...

Comment: But the code I see at the moment should create a `class_dct` holding the entire unpickled dict.

Comment: I've updated the code to show everything, and I fixed part of the pickle code. I had an unnecessary loop. The dataframe is tiny, so you might wonder why I need multiple classifiers. But I'll be working with a lot of data and want to classify first names within each last name.

The new data will have the same exact "last names" as the training data. I believe you were asking about that. In reality I'm not really working with last names but the training/testing/real data will have identical categories.

Comment: @tdelaney: Using protocol 2 explicitly would be the correct solution if this is Py2 code (which defaults to 0, which is a terrible protocol). If it's Py3, you'd want protocol 3 or 4 (and it defaults to 3, which is usually fine). Of course, if it really is Py2 code, you also want to do `try: import cPickle as pickle`, `except ImportError: import pickle` to get the C accelerated module if it's available (which is leaps and bounds faster and produces more compact output for the same data and protocol too). Not needed on Py3, where `import pickle` seamlessly gets the accelerated code when it can.